# Facebook PHP SDK 3.0 logout fully does not work

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to logout a user. I redirect the user to a logout page. This works ok. but in the logout page, i have a link redirecting to the login page, and when i go there, the user is already logged in... i have an echo to print the UserID...and its printing my user id!

This is my logout function:

```
function logoutUrl(&$facebook){
  $params = array('next'    => '(remaining url).../logout.php');
  return $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```

this is my login page:

```
<?php
include_once "fb_functions.php";
$facebook = getFBInstance();
echo getUser($facebook);
session_start();
?>
<body>
<div id="container"> 
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="body">
    <h2>
        <?php if (getUser($facebook)): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo logoutUrl($facebook); ?>">Logout</a>
            <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo loginUrl($facebook); ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
        <?php endif ?>
    </h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be useful: http://samoldak.com/fixing-facebooks-php-sdk-logout/